# Deriving the curvature operator in Misner, Thorne and Wheeler

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

This discussion is based on Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's Gravitation,
Box 11.5. I am having a hard time deriving the result which is stated
with the proof assigned as Exercise 11.1.

Let $\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B},\boldsymbol{C}$ be vector fields,
and $f$ a scalar function of position such that $f(\mathscr{P}_{0})=1$,
but is otherwise arbitrary. Define

$\boldsymbol{C}_{f}=f\boldsymbol{C}$.

The authors assert

$\left\{ \left[\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}},\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\right]\boldsymbol{C}_{f}\right\} _{at\mathscr{P}_{0}}-\left\{ \left[\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}},\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\right]\boldsymbol{C}\right\} _{at\mathscr{P}_{0}}=\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}f$.

Where $\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}f$
is the covariant derivative along the vector $\left[ \boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right] $.

Calculating the first term in the asserted equation produces

$\left[\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}},\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\right]\boldsymbol{C}_{f}=\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\left(\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}f+f\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{C}\right)-\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\left(\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}f+f\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{C}\right)$

$=\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\left(\boldsymbol{C}\right)\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}f+\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}f+\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\left(f\right)\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{C}+f\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{C}-\left(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\left(\boldsymbol{C}\right)\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}f+\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}f+\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\left(f\right)\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{C}+f\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{C}\right)$

$=\boldsymbol{C}\left(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}-\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\right)f+f\left(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}-\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\right)\boldsymbol{C}$.

So

$\left\{ \left[\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}},\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\right]\boldsymbol{C}_{f}\right\} _{at\mathscr{P}_{0}}-\left\{ \left[\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}},\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\right]\boldsymbol{C}\right\} _{at\mathscr{P}_{0}}=\boldsymbol{C}\left(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}-\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\right)f$.

Assuming the correctness of the assertion, we get

$\left(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}-\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\right)f=\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}f$.

For a scalar function the following equivalences hold.

$\left(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\partial\boldsymbol{_{\boldsymbol{B}}}-\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\partial\boldsymbol{_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\right)f=\left(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}}\boldsymbol{B}-\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\boldsymbol{A}\right)f\equiv\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]f$.

The authors define the cruvature operator as

$\mathscr{R}\left(\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right)\equiv\left[\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{A}}},\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{B}}}\right]-\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}$.

It, therefore, seems obvious that $\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}$is
not identical to $\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]$, even
if $\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]f=\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}f$.

Am I correct in concluding  $\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]f=\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You last conclusion, that $\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]f=\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}f$ for a $C^2$ scalar field $f$ is correct. The covariant derivative of a scalar field in the direction $\mathbf{A}$ is simply $\mathbf{A}\,f$, with $\mathbf{A}$ thought of as a first order differential operator, as you know.

The tangent bundle is closed with respect to the Lie bracket, so $[\mathbf{A},\,\mathbf{B}]$ is also a vector field whenever $\mathbf{A}$and $\mathbf{B}$ are, and $[\mathbf{A},\,\mathbf{B}]\,f$ is meaningful in the same way that $\mathbf{A}\,f$ and $\mathbf{B}\,f$ are: *i.e.* with the vector field $[\mathbf{A},\,\mathbf{B}]$ thought of as a first order differential operator.

So $\nabla_{[\mathbf{A},\,\mathbf{B}]}\,f$, being the covariant derivative in the direction $[\mathbf{A},\,\mathbf{B}]$ is simply another way of writing the same thing as $[\mathbf{A},\,\mathbf{B}]\,f$, for a scalar field $f$.

Comment: In the case of a scalar $\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]f=\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}f$ for a $C^2$ scalar field $f$ holds.  I was pretty sure of that.  What I'm not sure of is what it means to apply $\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}\boldsymbol{C}$  where $\boldsymbol{C}$ is a vector field.  In the case of a scalar field there is no affine connection term.  All I can legally justify at this point to subtract $\partial_{\left[\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{B}\right]}$ in the curvature operator.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, because it did address the question I stated explicitly.  I hope to revisit this matter.  For now, I must move on.